# Using a return value from a method that also has print statements

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, printing, return

I am working on a ROCK PAPER SCISSORS project for class and am trying to use a method which prints who wins the match and also return a value I'm using to determine who has the most wins.

However in the first method when I assign the method to a value to use it it prints out the statements in the evaluate method, is there any way around this or will I have to create another method that does the same thing just with out the print statements?

(userWins and computerWins are declared and initialized in main()  )

```
 main( ) {
        int userWins = 0;
        int computerWins = 0;

        .....

        int value = winEvaluation(userChoice, computerChoice);
        if (value == 1){
            userWins++;
        } else if (value == 2){
            computerWins++;
        } else{

        }

        System.out.prinln("user wins: " + userWins + " computer wins: " + computerWins);
 }

private static int evaluate(int userChoice, int computerChoice) {
    int winValue = 0;
    String win = "You win.";
    String lose = "I win.";
    String draw = "We picked the same thing! This round is a draw.";

    if( userChoice == 1) {

        if(computerChoice == 1){
            System.out.println(draw);
            winValue = 0;
        }else if(computerChoice == 2){
            System.out.print("PAPER covers ROCK." );
            System.out.println(lose);
            winValue = 2;
        }else {
            System.out.print("ROCK breaks SCISSORS.");
            System.out.println(win);
            winValue = 1;
        }

    }else if (userChoice == 2 ) {

        if (computerChoice == 1){
            System.out.print("PAPER covers ROCK.");
            System.out.println(win);
            winValue = 1;
        }else if (computerChoice == 2){
            System.out.println(draw);
            winValue = 0;
        }else {
            System.out.print("SCISSORS cuts PAPER.");
            System.out.println(lose);
            winValue = 2;
        }
    }else if (userChoice == 3){

        if (computerChoice == 1){
            System.out.print("ROCK breaks SCISSORS.");
            System.out.println(lose);
            winValue = 2;
        }else if (computerChoice == 2){
            System.out.print("SCISSORS cuts PAPER.");
            System.out.println(win);
            winValue = 1;
        }else {
            System.out.println(draw);
            winValue = 0;
        }

    }

    return winValue;
}
```

Comment: Side-effects (eg. print statements) and return values are not related. If you do not wish to perform the side-effect (eg. print statements) then don't do the side-effect. It would be better to remove the printing entirely and have a separate method which then prints out the value as appropriate.

Comment: `winEvaluation` != `evaluate`. Please post real code.

Comment: Ditto, this is unclear at the moment. The code is incomplete (the posted code only plays one round) and its not clear what you're trying to do or why the print statements aren't doing what you want.